# Download video in Downloads folder Android Q

Tags: android, android-10.0, scoped-storage

As per the restrictions of Android Q and above, I am trying to download the video file in Downloads folder under  folder. But It always takes to the Android/data/<package_name>/Downloads/ folder. minSdk for my app is API 16, and currently targetSdk is API 29.
Below is reference code snippet used.

```
String videoFileName = "video_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".mp4";
ContentValues valuesvideos;
valuesvideos = new ContentValues();
valuesvideos.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.RELATIVE_PATH, "Movies/" + "Folder");
valuesvideos.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.TITLE, videoFileName);
valuesvideos.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, videoFileName);
valuesvideos.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.MIME_TYPE, "video/mp4");
valuesvideos.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_ADDED, System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000);
valuesvideos.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_TAKEN, System.currentTimeMillis());
valuesvideos.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.IS_PENDING, 1);
ContentResolver resolver = mContext.getContentResolver();
Uri collection = MediaStore.Video.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY);
Uri uriSavedVideo = resolver.insert(collection, valuesvideos);

ParcelFileDescriptor pfd;
try {
    pfd = mContext.getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uriSavedVideo, "w");
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(pfd.getFileDescriptor());
    File storageDir = new File(mContext.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES), "Folder");
    File imageFile = new File(storageDir, "Myvideo");
    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(imageFile);

    byte[] buf = new byte[8192];
    int len;
    while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {

        out.write(buf, 0, len);
    }

    out.close();
    in.close();
    pfd.close();
} catch (Exception e) {

    e.printStackTrace();
}
valuesvideos.clear();
valuesvideos.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.IS_PENDING, 0);
mContext.getContentResolver().update(uriSavedVideo, valuesvideos, null, null);
```

Thank You in Advance.

Comment: Yes you use getExternalFilesDir which delivers that Android folder.

Comment: What do you mean with `download` ? I see no download. Maybe a copy of a file. And nothing in your code has anything with a `Download` folder name.